# Newtonsoft custom ignore convention

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I want to ignore certain properties in a class, but I want to keep the class POCO for many reasons. Hence I do not want to introduce dependency to Json.NET, and do not want to use `JsonIgnoreAttribute`.

Is there some way to customize the contract resolver to respect some other convention? Eg, properties that are named starting with the word "NonSerialized", for instance, or at least a custom attribute of our own choosing that is internally created (again to eliminate external dependency and keep the domain model as pure as possible).

Also different persistence will need to ignore/respect the same attribute differently, so it would be nice to be able to control what gets serialized at runtime via some kind of fluent api. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fields you can use `[NonSerializable]` attribute from System namespace, to avoid serialization. That way you have no dependency to external library. This doesn't work on properties.

For properties, there is a feature called **Conditional Property Serialization**. Basically, you implement method that returns boolean and follows naming convention - `ShouldSerialize[PropertyName]`.

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializePassword() { return false; }
}
```

This example would always avoid serializing `Password`. `ShouldSerialize` method can contain more complex validation logic, instead of simply returning false.

Comment: It's better than nothing, but I wished there was a way to do this outside of the domain model completely. But I'll take what I can get. Thanks for your help.